# Share a data context across various model repositories in ASP.NET MVC using LINQ2SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a 2 repositories in my application each with their own datacontext objects.

The end result has me attempting to attach an object retrieved from one repository to an object retrieved from a different repository which results in an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **Constructor Injection** to inject the DataContext into each Repository:

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly DataContext dataContext;

    public MyRepository(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        if(dataContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dataContext");
        }

        this.dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    // implement MyRepository using this.dataContext;
}
```

This allows you to share or not share the DataContext in whichever way is necessary.

Comment: why the ArgumentNullException if you're saying that "This allows you to share or not share the DataContext"?  I'm just trying to understand, thanks.

Comment: The Guard Clause is there to guarantee the invariants of the class. It has nothing to do with whether or not you can share the DataContext (which you can).

Comment: Thanks Mark. If I understood correctly, your proposed solution is having an extra constructor, so you will probably need one DataContext for each Controller? @Mark Seeman, thanks again! I read a lot of mvc pattern and finally I think I have this answer :O)

Comment: Not an *extra* constructor - *the* constructor.