# How do I share dbContext without CodeFirst in EntityFramework 4.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, oop, entity-framework-4.1

Long time lurker, first time poster.

I've found tons of stuff on here about how to share dbContext across repositories using CodeFirst, but I can't seem to relate that to the project I'm working on, which doesn't use code first or dependency injection.

First, a little background on the project to make sure that I'm approaching this the right way.  I came into this project and they were using EF4 and with a DB first.  I'm far from an expert on EF, but I've fumbled around with several different projects now.

I've had to implement several different requirements that have forced me to intervene between their "service" level and the database.  In other words, their objects were making calls directly to the EF db objects like

```
using (var db = new MYDB()){
  var bar = db.Foo
   .Include("Transactions")
   .Include("blah")
   .Where(...);

  //do stuff

  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

One thing I had to do was track all fields that changed, so I abstracted back a level and now we have

```
FooObject bar = GetFooObject(...);
bar.Title = "asdfasdf";
//do stuff to bar
bar.Save();
```

which wraps up all the fields into properties so I can log out any changes.  In bar.save I open a db context, get the existing Foo or create a new one, assign all the values and then call db.SaveChanges.

As it turns out they also do lots of sub-queries based on Transactions and blah.  So when they do something like

```
var bar = GetFooObject(...);

var t = new Transaction();
//do stuff to t
...
bar.Transactions.Add(t);
bar.Save();
```

I get hit with all kinds of context errors saying that the dbcontext is no longer available etc.  Which I totally understand.  What I don't know is how to fix it.  I've seen lots of stuff about creating a dbContext before it's used and then passing it in, but I can't seem to figure out the proper way to do it so it will work with my code.

My most recent attempt based on several examples about how to convert DBContext to ObjectContext (which was in turn based on the fact that all of the examples I found about sharing a connection referenced ObjectContext and not DBContext) looks like this:

```
using (var db = ((IObjectContextAdapter)(new FooDB())).ObjectContext)
  {
using (var context = new DbContext(db, false))
{
var bar = FooObject.GetFooObject(fooId);
Result r = bar.ProcTrans(amount,
                        transDate,
                            db.TransactionTypes
                              .Include(tt => tt.Description)
                              .SingleOrDefault(tt => tt.TypeID == transactionTypeId),
                            employeeId,
                            comment);
```

But with this code I get an error that I have no definition for TransactionTypes.  It doesn't recognize any of my db Objects.

How can I create a DBContext and pass it to my FooObject so that I can keep it open for the related updates?  I don't even know if I'm asking the question exactly right.   How do I bridge this gap without recoding the whole thing?

### **EDIT**

Here are some things I've found since opening this question.  Maybe one of the two will do the trick.

Well, this finding certainly is more along the lines of recoding the whole thing but I did find this when looking for links regarding the "do change tracking" with triggers response.

[poco in the entity framework part-3: change tracking with poco](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/10/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-3-change-tracking-with-poco.aspx)

And I just found this [how do I share a data context across various model repositories in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030665/how-do-i-share-a-data-context-across-various-model-repositories-in-asp-net-mvc-u) which might be a simple way to approach it.

Comment: I think you are way overthinking this problem.  It's difficult to tell from you vague hand waving and incomplete examples what you are really trying to do, but i'd take a step back.  Change tracking should be done at the database level, using triggers.  If you do that, then you reduce a great deal of complexity with your problem.

Comment: I found numerous articles and examples that said change tracking using triggers was a horrible idea in the long run largely for maintenance reasons.  Do you have any links or experience otherwise?  I considered that approach, but research pointed me elsewhere.

I have stepped back numerous times and I'm left with the same problem.  How do I maintain DBContext across multiple queries?

Comment: As for the vagary, I'm sorry.  I'm asking a rather high level / indirect question.  My code samples are sufficient to get the point across.  I'm not asking for help with my syntax.  I'm asking how to share DBContext without references to Code First.  I'm not using repositories or Dependency Injection.

Comment: I don't think the change tracking with POCO will work for me.  I've already implemented those interfaces but as I understand it, I wouldn't be able to actually log the changes without setting up a "change listener" for each object to log the changes.  See here:[INotifyPropertyChanged in POCO entities](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/adodotnetentityframework/thread/42463fb2-d8e6-4b91-a084-47e704c76b9a)

Comment: By implementing change trackign in the app, then there is no tracking of changes made manually, either by non-EF code, a user using SQL Management Studio, or a direct query executed on the Database.  Change tracking implemented with triggers will see changes regardless of their source, and is thus much more reliable.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it another look.  At first glance, it looks like I'm going to create a whole new level of complexity and management, which I'm not crazy about.  But if it's the best / only way to go then so be it.  That's a good point about changes made directly to the db.  In our case, that _shouldn't_ ever happen.

Comment: Change tracking is an intrusive process, You have to intercept each and every change and log it.  It's not something that should be an afterthought.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but for right or wrong, I wasn't ready to open a whole new can of worms and complexity to manage change tracking in triggers when I already have a pretty elegant tracking solution in place at the object level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave behind the object context stuff.

The way I achieve a shared DBContext in my MVC app is like this:

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    public static MyAppContext GetDataContext()
    {
        string ocKey = "ocm_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x");

        if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(ocKey))
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(ocKey, new MyAppContext());

        return HttpContext.Current.Items[ocKey] as MyAppContext;
    }
}
```

Then whenever I need to do a database operation I can call:

```
BaseRepository.GetDataContext().YourObjects.Where(x => ...);
....
BaseRepository.GetDataContext().SaveChanges();
```

As long as you are still in the same HTTP context you will be sharing the same DB Context.  Not entirely sure this will eliminate the errors that you are getting, but it's at least a way to share your context.

Comment: That's pretty sweet.  Certainly a nice shortcut!  I found another link at some point that did something similar but they were storing the reference in the thread I think... I can't find the link now.  Ironically, your answer popped up as I was typing in mine. :)  I'll keep this in mind for the future.  It seems like a faster way to get to where I got to.

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of the answers as the accepted answer. :)  Thanks for the feedback and up vote.

Comment: I'll mark yours since you took the time to write it up, and I think it is a valid solution to the problem I was encountering, even though it isn't exactly the one I used.  See below for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, for me, was related to one of the links I posted.

[how do I share a data context across various model repositories in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030665/how-do-i-share-a-data-context-across-various-model-repositories-in-asp-net-mvc-u)

What threw me off when I saw these types of injection answers was that syntactically they didn't work for me.  I don't have DataContext nor do I have any Repository models, but I decided to give it a try conceptually and pass the Context around everywhere.

Basically, I passed in the connection to the Object constructor or to any factory methods where a new object is created and store that in a local variable, sorta like this.

```
public class Foo{
    private MyDB _db;
    private Foo _foo;

    public FooObject(MyDB dbContext)
    {
        _db = dbContext;
    }

    public static FooObject GetFooObject(int FooID, MyDB db){
        bool closeFlag = false;

        //if null was passed in, then we will create our own connection and manage it
        if (db == null)
        {
            _db = new MyDB();
            closeFlag = true;
        } else {
            //otherwise, we set our local variable
            _db = db;
        }

        //from now on, all queries are done using the local variable
        var _f = _db.Foos
            .Include("x")
            .Include("y")
            .Include("z")
            .SingleOrDefault(f => f.FooID == FooID);

        var fo = FooObjectFromFoo(_f, db);

        if (closeFlag)
            db.Dispose();

        return fo;
    }

    // This copies all of the values from Foo and puts the into a FooObject
    public static FooObject FooObjectFromFoo(Foo f, MyDB dbContext){
        if (l == null)
            return null;

        // note that we pass the dbContext to the constuctor
        FooObject _f = new FooObject(dbContext){
            _foo = f,
            ...
            //note x, y, and z are the other EF "table references".  I'm not sure what you technically call them.
            x = f.x,
            y = f.y,
            z = f.z
        };

        return _f;
    }


    //we call this to save the changes when we're done
    public bool Save(){
        bool close = false; 
        bool retval = true;

        MyDB db = _db;

        //remember we set _db in the constructor            
        if (db == null) {
            db = new MyDB();
            close = true;
        }

        try
        {
            // a reference to this row should have been saved in _foo if we loaded it from the db.
            // take a look at FooObjectFromFoo
            if (_foo == null)
            {
                _foo = db.Foos.SingleOrDefault(x => x.FooID == _FooID);
            }
            if (_foo == null)
            {
                _foo = new Foo();
            }
            //copy all my object values back to the EF Object
            _foo.blah = blah;
            _foo.x = x;
            _foo.y = y;
            try
            {
                //save the new one.
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                TransactionResult.AddErrors(dbEx);
                retval = false;
            }
        }
        catch { throw new Exception("Something went wrong here.");}
        finally { if (close) db.Dispose(); } //if we created this connection then let's close it up.
    }
}
```

And now in my methods, I always use the local _db connection.  Outside of my FooObject we have a FooService which is what is called from all of the controllers.  So when FooService is instantiated I create a db connection using my class below.
If I understand it properly, this should give me a context that exists for the duration of my service request which, in my case, fairly reliably mimics the request.

```
namespace My.Domain
{
  public class MyDataContext : IDisposable  {
    private MyDB _context;
    private bool _ownContext;

    public MyDataContext(){
        _context = new MyDB();
        _ownContext = true;
    }

    public MyDataContext(MyDB db)
    {
        _context = db;
        _ownContext = false;
    }

    public MyDB Context
    {
        get { if (_context == null) { _context = new MyDB(); _ownContext = true; } return _context; }
        set { _context = value; }
    }

    public bool OwnContext
    {
        get { return _ownContext; }
        set { _ownContext = value; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_context != null && _ownContext)
            _context.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

In the FooService I do stuff like this.

```
    private MyDb db;

    public FooService (){
        var _db = new MyDataContext();
        db = _db.Context;
    }

    public Result ProcessTransaction(int FooId, string comment)
    {
        var foo = FooObject.GetFooObject(FooId,db);

        Result r = foo.ProcessTransaction(comment);

        if (r.Success)
            foo.Save();

        return r;
    }
```

I think to do it "right" I should only save the changes when I close out the context... but I already had a Save method on my FooObject, so I just call db.SaveChanges in there.

I know there are lots of ways to improve this and I'm sure I'll implement some of them over time, but for now, this did the trick.  This was how I got around all of the "Context is no longer available" and this object was from a different context errors.

The thing that tripped me up when looking at other peoples examples is they were all using CodeFirst and dependency injection of some sort.  They commonly used Repository patterns and we don't have any of that.  But it turns out that I just had to implment my own hacked-up localized version of connection injection! :)

Comment: I've realized since I did this, that the MyDataContext class I made is basically useless.  I create the db instance in the FooService and pass it around from there.  I could have just as easily created the instance in the FooService constructor.   hmmm.  Maybe if MyDataContext used the trickery from Ben Tidman then it could be useful... interesting.